# Repetitive Node.js requests to MongoDB slow down eventually

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have data going into a MongoDB collection `rmc` and it's being upserted, i.e. I have one point with the latest latitude and longitude for my device.

From Node.js, I'd like to query that collection every `100 ms` (to simulate real time) and update a map with the updated latitude / longitude.

I get good performance at first, but right after having updated data in my collection or just a while, the performance starts getting really bad.

What am I doing wrong? Could I do things in a better way? I can't seem to figure out if **MongoDB** or **Node**, or **Mongoose**.

The user goes to `index.html`, which fetches an HTML page. Within the HTML, I request a page every 100 ms:

```
function updateData() {
  $.getJSON("/data", function(json) {
    dosomething()
    interval = setTimeout(updateData, 100);
  })
};

updateData();
```

And my index.js:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: "test" });
});

router.get('/data', function(req, res, next) {
  var db = req.db;
  Json.find({}).select({}).lean().exec(function(e,docs){
    res.json(docs);
  });
});
```

Things are good and all of a sudden, there is huge delay being experienced:

```
GET /data 304 1.644 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.738 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.685 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.693 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.624 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.645 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.873 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.607 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.638 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.610 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.734 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.736 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.660 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.634 ms - -
GET /data 304 15.265 ms - -
GET /data 304 10.535 ms - -
GET /data 304 1.740 ms - -
GET /data 304 70.184 ms - -
GET /data 304 69.037 ms - -
GET /data 304 58.620 ms - -
GET /data 304 75.053 ms - -
GET /data 304 72.292 ms - -
GET /data 304 92.447 ms - -
GET /data 304 95.270 ms - -
GET /data 304 448.057 ms - -
GET /data 304 567.309 ms - -
GET /data 304 683.199 ms - -
GET /data 304 731.952 ms - -
GET /data 304 1102.502 ms - -
GET /data 304 1770.029 ms - -
GET /data 304 1051.307 ms - -
GET /data 304 1059.791 ms - -
```

Comment: so I think node.js / mongoose keeps some kind of artifacts in memory after each call and therefore my server quickly saturates. Is there any way I could clean the memory while the script is executing?

Comment: I'm getting much better performance with mongoskin, but still, after a bit, something fills up and the behaviour above is found. FYI I completely commented my code and only trigger calls to the /data route to troubleshoot

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should consider using Redis cache instead of querying the same data over and over again, you'll get much better performance. I don't see anything wrong with your code however and that slow down shouldn't happen.

Comment: Could you post CPU and RAM usage over time as well? For the node and mongodb processes.

Comment: My limited understanding was that it could take up to 100ms for mongo to flush a write to disk, perhaps you are calling it slightly faster than it can keep up?

Comment: flushing data to disk is irrelevant here as it's happening asynchronously.  what we don't know is what the activity on the collection is, and whether the data is growing (and maybe the query isn't efficiently indexed).

Comment: It makes sense to measure query running time inside your route. But basically, more information is required: what is your model & query, what are your indexes in the db, how many data are in the database.

Comment: var db = req.db; is doing what here? are you requiring your mongoose schema based on req. more code is needed.

Comment: You should try and replicate the problem with the Node.js MongoDB driver... if the problem doesn't happen at least you will know that the problem is related to Mongoose.

Comment: Did you try this locally? Is the browser is running on the same machine as your server? It's possible that `dosomething()` does somthing with your memory / cpu and steal resources from mongodb

Answer (score 1):

There might be different ways for profiling the node application to find out where the issue come from. Using native node you can try running you app:

```
 node --prof <entrypoint>.js
```

Then try to run your test to allow node to gather some data, when finished a file will be generated that has to be converted to something with a better human friendly output

```
node --prof-process <file_generate>.log > processed.txt
```

Getting into processed.txt you can find which parts of your code spend more CPU time so can point you to potentially the place where the issue might come from.

For more detailed info, there is a quite good entry in node docs about analyzing profiling files https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are piping the output to many functions which don't do much. Also, if the output is small then it seems okay to send all the data as response. Try modifying your code to

```
const docs = await Json.find({})
res.json(docs)
```

You don't need lean() or select(). They are doing nothing

Answer (score 0):

You must see the execution time of the query in your code and together with the full code (can use console statements for this).And see whether its the query that takes up the time or any other piece of code.At same time moniter the cpu usage and see which process is taking how much resources.
You can see the execution stats of any mongodb query 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/

Additionally run mongoose in debug mode in development.

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To increase your mongoDB performance you can do these 2 things:

1. Adjusting connection pools; this way your code will re-use the existing connections than creating new connections everytime you do some operations, by default its 5 try scaling it.
2. Creating indexes in your collection; create an unique/ compound index, this will for sure increase your query performance.

Additionally you can run explain command to see your entire query execution and profiling.

Check this out: [MongoDB Performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/)